# Call to undefined method RegistrationController::getEngine() in

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Everything worked fine. And then suddenly started getting this error. 
On the local computer.

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Adwordsup\SecurityBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::getEngine() in /var/www/adwords-up/src/Adwordsup/SecurityBundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php line 68
```

On hosting all is well. Compared. Noticed a difference only that the different structures. 

**Local:** friendsofsymfony/userbundle/

**Hosting:** friensofsymfony/userbundle/FOS/UserBundle/
Extension possible after updating the bundle flew. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The getEngine() method has been removed. I Just pass the extension of my template statically (.twig for example).

Answer (score 0):

The getEngine() method has been removed. You can do the following in your controller and it will work:

```
return $this->render('yourtemplatename.html.twig', $array);
```